# sap.m.Input allow only positive integer values

Tags: sapui5

I need reject for sap.m.Input control any input except integer values. So in input may be inputted only 0-9, without any sign symbol(+-) or any decimal separators. I Can't find good solution. View declared in XML format, and preferable way is just change this XML with additional parameters, if it possible.

Possible solutions:

- The first one - write custom formatter.
- The second one - try to find some standard solution with types. I found internal data types and they settings, but it seems that they not working well.

Answer (score 6):

A custom formatter won't help you in this case as its only used oneway (model->view).

But data types are your friend here. I would suggest `sap.ui.model.type.Integer` with a minimum constraint of 0.

```xml
<Input value="{path: '/value', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer', constraints:{minimum:0}}" />
```

However this does have two prerequisites:

1. You need to enable complex databinding. This can be done in the bootstrap tag in index.html with the [data-sap-ui-compatVersion](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9feb96da02c2429bb1afcf6534d77c79.html) attribute. Version 1.26 is needed at least. You can use the value *edge* to specify the newest version:

```xml
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" 
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge">
```

Alternatively you can use [data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html).

2. If the user enters invalid data the datatype throws a `ValidationException`. The error will be silently ignored but the model won't be updated. To get some feedback for the user you can register the control or the whole view at the [MessageManager](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8c4e534cdb440e9a5bbff86f9572bd6.html):

```js
sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject(this.getView(), true);
```

You can also enable [handleValidation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7.html) in the Component or when instantiating the component.

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yepesediza/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 2):

Regex is your friend here.

Here is a pretty [simple jsbin](http://jsbin.com/napajo) I re-used from someone validating text only and modified the regex to accept numbers only.

You could wire the validation into the change event so it would fire and set the state to error if text entered.

Let us know how this works out.

Cheers,

Nigel

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm searching the way to implement this by standard features. I thought about using regex and change event, but this is not very clean way to do it, I think. But if there is no other way to do it, well, I'll do it in this way.